# Django - How to add data to a ManyToMany field model?

Tags: django

I have the following models, view and template:

models.py:

```
class Batch(models.Model):
    material_id = models.ManyToManyField(AssetMetadata)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Batch_' + str(self.pk) + '_' + self.user.username

class AssetMetadata(models.Model):

    material_id = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True)
    series_title = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True)
    season_title = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True)
    season_number = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    episode_title = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True)
    episode_number = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    synopsis = models.TextField(max_length=1024, blank=True)
    ratings = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.material_id
```

views.py:

```
def assets_in_repo(request):

    asset_list = AssetMetadata.objects.order_by('id').all()
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    paginator = Paginator(asset_list, 50)

    try:
        assets = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        assets = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        assets = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    if request.method == 'POST':

        batch_list = request.POST.getlist('batch')
        print(batch_list)

    return render(request, 'assets_db/assets.html', {'assets': assets})
```

snippet from template:

```
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" value="Create Batch" align="right">
    <table class="table table-striped" id="myTable">
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Material ID</th>
            <th>Series Title</th>
            <th>Season Tile</th>
            <th>Season Number</th>
            <th>Episode Title</th>
            <th>Episode Number</th>
            <th>Create Batch</th>
        </tr>
        {%  for i in assets %}<tr>
            <td>{{i.pk}}</td>
            <td><a href="/repo/{{ i.id}}">{{i.material_id}}</a></td>
            <td>{{i.series_title}}</td>
            <td>{{i.season_title}}</td>
            <td>{{i.season_number}}</td>
            <td>{{i.episode_title}}</td>
            <td>{{i.episode_number}}</td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="batch" value="{{i.pk}}">
            </td>
        </tr>{% endfor %}
    </table>
    </form>
```

I am trying to get the data provided from the checkbox and save it in the `Batch` model.

The user selects assets to create a batch, the form returns the `pk` for these assetss in `AssetMetadata` and the selections are stored in a list create via `batch_list = request.POST.getlist('batch')`. I want to use the data stored in this list to create a new entry in `Batch` which then links to the asset `pk` in `AssetMetadata`.

I have been able to do this successfully in the Django admin page but i would ideally do this in teh view.

I have read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/relations/ and search stackoverflow but i am stumped as how to do this.

Comment: Side note, your definition of the `id` field on the AssetMetadata field definitely isn't doing what you expect. It's just defining a class attribute called `id` with a static value of whatever `auto_creation_counter` is at the time of import.

Comment: Yep that's what i want, basically it increments as new assets are added to the archive.

Comment: But it *doesn't*, that's my point. It's a static value set for the *class as a whole*, set on import. Django automatically gives models a primary key value which auto increments, you should just use that.

Comment: Ahh yes i see what you are saying, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
info = Batch.objects.create(season_title ='foo', .....)
info2= AssetMetadata.objects.create(material_id ='some')
info.material_id.add(info2)
```

try something like this

Answer (score 2):

I think you need

```
obj = AssetMetadata.objects.get(id=pk)
obj.batch_set.add(* batch_list)
```

Comment: the `*` is incredibly important.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to help from both answers I was able to get this working, this is how i did it:

```
def assets_in_repo(request):

    asset_list = AssetMetadata.objects.order_by('id').all()
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    paginator = Paginator(asset_list, 50)

    try:
        assets = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        assets = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        assets = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    if request.method == 'POST':

        batch_list = request.POST.getlist('batch')

        info = Batch.objects.create(user_id=request.user.id)
        for item in batch_list:
            info.material_id.add(item)
```